# How to avoid SSL certification error in Selenium Webdriver using Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Here's a simple python code to go to a particular website:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

profile=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver =webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Utility_Tools\WebDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('www.google.com')
```

But since I haven't entered the url so it throws error. Whereas if I use this statement:

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Error Disappears.
Since my database contains websites without SSL certifications is there any way to browse through them only?
Here's my attempt but this too failed:

```
profile=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver =webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Utility_Tools\WebDriver\chromedriver.exe',options=profile)
driver.get('www.google.com')
```

The error I trigger each time I run the code is shown below:

> errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid
>   argument   (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)

Comment: Note that when I use the webpage with proper SSL certification link, the error disappears.

Comment: _so it throws error._ **What error?** Always include the entire error message.

Comment: I can't tell what you're doing but --disable-web-security makes those go away sometimes

Comment: Error is mentioned at the end @AMC.

Comment: Hi @pguardiario, the answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on `get()`, `www.google.com` is not a valid url. For not secure you can use `http` rather than `https`

```
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: Actually Its working with https. What I want to know is that since all my websites are without http tag then how can I figure out the way to browse without specifying http certifications.

Comment: @ShivamSahil all websites have `http` or `https`, otherwise it's not a valid url. If you store the urls without it just add it in the code `'http://' + 'www.google.com'`

Comment: @ShivamSahil yes.

Comment: @ShivamSahil _so even if it has https, will it still work?_ Make sure you understand what the issue was, https itself has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @AMC Actually my issue was without SSL certifications, selenium was not working and error was as shown above. So I needed to know if there's a method to use SSL certification directly. I understand that https has no specific role. Thanks.